# How to evaluate the query by supplying a variable whose value is evaluated at runtime?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a piece of code where I want to return total number of documents in a specific forest. I want to determine whether a forest doc count is 0 or more.

```
 declare function local:forest-doc-count($db-name,
                                        $f-id as xs:unsignedLong) as xs:integer {
  let $_ := xdmp:log(xdmp:describe(fn:concat("$db-name -->", $db-name), (),()))                    
    let $query := 'xquery version "1.0-ml";
                    declare variable $f-id as xs:unsignedLong external;
                   xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), (), (), (), $f-id))'
    let $count := xdmp:eval($query , (),
                    map:entry("f-id",   $f-id),
                    map:entry("database", xdmp:database($db-name))
                    )
    return $count
};
```

where **$f-id** is forest Id and **$db-name** is Database name. For now I'm getting

> Undefined variable $f-id

Answer (score 5):

Declare an external variable in the query and then bind a value to the external variable in the call.

The following sketch is untested, but something along these lines should work:

```
declare function local:forest-doc-count(
    $db-name as xs:string,
    $f-id    as xs:unsignedLong
) as xs:integer {
    xdmp:eval(
        'xquery version "1.0-ml";
         declare variable $f-id as xs:unsignedLong external;
         xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), (), (), (), $f-id))',
        map:entry("f-id",     $f-id),
        map:entry("database", xdmp:database($db-name))
        )
};
```

A footnote:  You might want to declare the type of parameters and return values when they are determinate to take advantage of type checking.

Hoping that's useful,

Comment: arg4 is not of type xs:string. This is what I'm receiving.

Comment: I fixed two typos in the code. Did you copy it literally? Like this it works fine for me, when calling it with `local:forest-doc-count(xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database()), xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database())[1])`

Comment: No I didn't literally copy pasted it. For me it's not working. I even put a log and checked the error logs. I see a string for $db-name. I'm still getting the same error `arg4 is not of type xs:string`. I have updated the code so now you'll can still check for errors further.

Comment: Ohh! Ok Its working for me now. I just removed `()` the 2nd argument from xdmp:eval at it is working. But I'll appreciate if someone can elaborate on my mistake as the 2nd argument, i.e. the empty sequence was optional so what was wrong in it ?

Comment: The second argument is the external variable runtime definitions. Once you add the external variable declaration to the query being eval'd, it's not optional any longer.